# What is the value passed to a lambda when part of a Linq expression?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, lambda

If I have:

```
public Dictionary<string, int> ChangeDictionary(Dictionary<string, int> myDictionary)
        {
            myDictionary.OrderBy(a => rnd.Next());
        }
```

What is "a"?  I know it is the parameter of the anonymous function, but I don't know what this syntax is called.  I couldn't tell from the MSDN documentation.  Is "a" the dictionary `myDictionary`?

EDIT:  Sorry.  By what is "a", " I mean what is getting passed in as the value for the parameter `a`.  Is it myDictionary?

Comment: `a` is a `KeyValuePair<string, int>`. If you inspect the call `OrderBy()` it takes an `IEnumerable<T>`. It provides you with an argument `T`. In the case of `Dictionary`, it implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`

Comment: Is this clear for you now? If so, you may consider marking the answer as accepted. If it isn't, let us know.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I don't know. Not mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "a" is a parameter. Your lambda could be rewritten:

```
private int MyOrderSelector(KeyValuePair<string, int> a)
{
    return rnd.Next();
}
```

You just call it a parameter, as far as I can tell. Its type depends on the signature of the lambda. In this case `OrderBy` expects a `Func<KeyValuePair<string, int>, int>`.

You can tell what type `a` is through intellisense, or when using LINQ; the argument is a single item in the collection being enumerated. Since `Dictionary` is a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, V>>` the items are also `KeyValuePair`.

To the edit, in this *specific* case your lambda is called repeatedly, with each item in the dictionary taking its turn as the parameter value. More generally, the value of `a` is whatever the caller passed as the first argument.

Comment: I'm asking where does the value of "a" come from.

Comment: @johnny From the caller; a lambda is a function and doesn't do anything unless called